# Unrecognized selector sent to instance: Swift 2 NSTimer setup

Tags: swift, nstimer

I've read the other posts. I've read the docs. I've read nearly everything I can get my hands on in regards to this issue, but it persists. To be clear, this problem ONLY happens if I want to capture the timer as a parameter in the receiving function.

Here's the error:

```
2016-03-07 18:26:29.000 AlarmClockAI[12286:3807622] -[AlarmClockAI.Alarm playAlarm]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd0936289e0
```

I have a class derived from NSObject.  In that class, I'm creating a series of timers like so:

```
timer = NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 5.0, target: self, selector:      Selector("playAlarm:"), userInfo: ["UUID":UUID], repeats: false)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

func playAlarm(timer: NSTimer) {}
```

I still get the unrecognized selector error.

Other variations I've tried:

```
NSTimer(fireDate: fireDate, interval: 5.0, target: self, selector:"playAlarm:", userInfo: ["UUID":UUID], repeats: false)
```

Same error.

Other notes:

- I'm running Swift 2.1.1
- I realize I shouldn't need the @objc tag, but I've tried that too.
- Clean + build + restart didn't help.
- FML

Comment: is the play alarm method part of the Alarm class or is it declared in the same block of code as your timer is called?

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that something is calling "playAlarm" instead of "playAlarm:".  Maybe check for a typo.

Comment: What is AlarmClockAI.Alarm?

Comment: Blake -- The timers are created in a class method called createTimers, and the playAlarm method belongs to the same class.

Comment: Philip -- That is strange.  I thought the colon after the closing bracket in -[AlarmClockAI.Alarm playAlarm]: indicated the parm, but I'm not sure.  Sounds like my assumption was wrong.

Comment: Shripada -- I'm building an alarm clock app, and AlarmClockAI.Alarm is the class that encapsulates the timers, notifications, and methods necessary to manage the individual alarms.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score -1):

Ugh.  Sorry guys.  I found the answer: I have more than one method that creates timers, and I was looking at the wrong one.